# Parametrizing a counterclockwise spiral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

I am looking for someone who could help explaining the solution to this question? Especially how they came up with the paramaterization and why it would be cos(t+ pi/2) and sin(t + pi/2) instead of cos(t) and sin(t).

Thanks a lot!!

[image]

Comment: If you write $x(t) = t^2 \cos(t + \alpha)$ and $y(t) = t^2 \sin(t + \alpha)$ and then impose $x(2\pi) = 0$ and $y(2\pi) = 4\pi^2$, you find $\cos(\alpha) = 0$ and $\sin(\alpha) = 1$., which are satisfied by $\alpha = \pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks but isn't cos(t+a), how come we are allowed to write as cos(a)?

Comment: It's just that $\cos(2\pi + \alpha) = \cos(\alpha)$ and $\sin(2\pi + \alpha) = \sin(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks!! So the interpretation is that (x(t),y(t)) = (0,4pi^2) and this point is at t=2pi? But why is t=2pi at this coordinate? (or why is it this angle? Particularly we are facing "North", or pi/2)

Comment: Yes, we are "facing North," as you say, and that's where the phase shift of $\pi/2$ comes into play: $\cos(x + \pi/2)$ is ahead of $\cos(x)$ by $\pi/2$.  By adding $\pi/2$ to sine and cosine, we rotate the whole spiral clockwise by $\pi/2$.  The fact that $t=2\pi$ when the spiral goes through $(0,4\pi)$ comes from the fact that $r=t^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question about the phase shift of $\pi/2$ is very easy to understand if we look at this problem in the complex plane. Let

$$z(t)=t^2e^{i(t^2+\pi/2)}=t^2e^{\pi/2}e^{it^2}=it^2e^{it^2}$$

So, the difference between $t^2$ and $(t^2+\pi/2)$ boils down to a factor of $i$, which translates to a $90^{\circ}$ CCW rotation of $z$. In fact, any phase shift will translate to a rotation of that amount in the complex plane. In your problem, if the $\pi/2$ is omitted, then the $4\pi$ point would fall on the $x$-axis rather than the $y$-axis. Continuing along with the complex plane, the arc length is given by

$$s=\int |\dot z|dt$$

$$\dot z=i[it^2+2t]e^{it}=(-t^2+i2t)e^{it}$$

$$|\dot z|=\sqrt{t^4+4t^2}=t\sqrt{t^2+4}$$

and finally, as shown by Wilson

$$s=\int_0^{2\pi} |\dot z|dt=\frac{(t^2+4)^{3/2}}{3}\big{|}_0^{2\pi}=\frac{8}{3} \left((1+\pi^2)^{3/2}-1\right)$$

I find that many problems are much more easily formulated, solved, and understood in the complex plane.